# setTimeout() / setInterval() stops when right click on IE

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, contextmenu, settimeout

I've got a countdown on my website done with setTimeout() but I realize that with Internet Explorer 11 (and older I guess) when the user right clicks anywhere on the browser, the countdown just stops because the "context menu" from the browser is open. The countdown starts back when the context menu is close.

The solution of blocking the rightclick during this countdown is not an usable solution in my case.
I've also check the requestAnimationFrame() method, but if the user minimize the browser, the countdown also stops.

The countdown is not lasting forever, it can last from 3 minutes to 10 seconds.

Any workaround/ideas ?

Thanks

Comment: well what is the code you are using for a countdown? My guess is you are not using the clock, but using the timing intervals...

Comment: My function is just showing (more or less) the countdown and calling itself recursively until the user click on it or the countdown equal 0.

setTimeout("CountDownWrapUp(" + lineId + "," + (secs - 1) + "," + randomnumber + ")", 1000);

Comment: Well there you go setTimeout ain't accurate, timers need to be based off clock time

Comment: Ok thanks, gonna try that. But it seems like the rightclick (the opening of the context menu in fact) is blocking the execution of the setTimeout().. Even if I do it on clock time, wouldn't the problem be the same here ?

Comment: Well if the Javascript is blocked, than there is not much you can do other than use something that calculates the time difference correctly when it restarts.

Answer (score 2):

You can't rely on `setTimeout` or `setInterval` to track time. They will approximately run when they are meant to but it is dependent on what else is taking up processing time and some blocking events like you have discovered. You should think of them as a way to update your clock but maintain the clock state as a differential between the time you started and the time your timer function fires. Because the timing of when the function fires isn't exact I try to set the interval lower than what I want. If I want it to tick every second then I set the interval to a half or quarter second to ensure that I make up for misses quicker.

Here is a rough example:

```js
function countdown(duration) {
  const start = Date.now();
  const interval = window.setInterval(function() {
     const remaining = duration - (Date.now() - start);
     if (remaining <= 0) {
        console.log(0);
        window.clearInterval(interval);
        return;
     }
     console.log(remaining);
  }, 500);
}

countdown(5000);
```

Comment: Just FYI, you can't use arrow functions - OP specifically mentions (and added a tag for) IE.  Just change it for a regular function ;)

Comment: Thanks bygrace, I manage to do something with your example. But is there any ways to do the same without setInterval() ? As I mentionned, the problem is that when rightclicking, the countdown just stops. With your example based on the time, yes it keeps track of the real time for the countdown down, which is nice. But I need to know when the countdown equal to 0.

Comment: @user3590062 you can get approximately there by setting up your interval to divide evenly into your countdown. Alternatively to `setInterval` you can do a recursive `setTimeout` and if the remaining time is less than the interval then do the timeout for the remaining time. You cannot guarantee that something will run at an exact time. Even if you pushed the timer into a web-worker the UI thread would still have to be responsive to it. So you really only have one thread to work with and if it gets busy then you will just have to wait.

Comment: Im not sure to understand correctly but, setTimeout has the same behavior than setInterval, it stops when there is a rightclick. I can't use that alternatively. And yes, it seems that I only have one thread to work with, so there is no really workaround/solutions ?

Comment: @user3590062 The difference with `setTimeout` is that it lets you vary your interval as you go. So if you observe that the difference between now and when your countdown ends is less than your interval then you can shorten it. Yes, there is no solution to guarantee that you can execute code exactly at a specific time.